# Building IOS applications and charging the seller without using IAP

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, appstore-approval

This might be a repeated question but I have not find the answer yet 
suppose that i want to develop a new ios application that might be used with our customers to collect data concerning them.(for example take orders from outlets, survey data, make a a field inspection...etc)

the application uses a backend application server (developed by us) to login and download lookups data for the IPhone application (such as list of outlets, type of questions...etc). these data are specified previously by our customers though a web application.
my question is, will apple charges our customer of using such service? supposing that the ios application is free and published into apple store?
the application may have a trail account for use by other customers

regards,

Answer (score 2):

Apple won't charge your customers for anything you don't charge them for in your application.  If you sell items via IAP, they get a cut.  If your iOS app is free and uses a service the user is paying for, that's fine.  There are numerous examples of applications that connect to paid-for applications like Basecamp, FreshBooks, Harvest, GitHub, Evernote, and Netflix.